# How to use the Dash to search for files on other drives?

Tags: 11.04, files, unity-dash, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zeitgeist does not index folders in NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43831/zeitgeist-does-not-index-folders-in-ntfs-partition)

I am new to Ubuntu and it's promising. My question is how can I use it to search for files like I could in the Start menu of Windows 7? Presently it just shows some file names if they were used very recently and in the present session. Is this a problem because my files (mostly music) are on a different drive than the one in which Ubuntu is installed?

Comment: For your second question, note that while the StackExchange sites are linked, you have separate accounts for each one. So reputation, questions, answers, etc. are all separate on each site. You can view all your separate accounts in the accounts tab on your profile, [like this.](http://askubuntu.com/users/24507/danny?tab=accounts)

Comment: what about the first ques??

Comment: @Danny If your files are on a different drive, you may have to [mount that drive](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountwindows) (assuming that's your Windows drive) first before you can search for them.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not an expert in Unity and I don't really use it. If I had to take a guess, I would say it's likely that Unity isn't indexing the files on your other drive so it's not coming up in the search. I could be wrong though. Be patient, someone will likely leave an answer soon.

Comment: @Danny I'll make one additional note: your second question would be better placed on [Meta] and taken off of this one.

Comment: i ll do that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dash is a shell in Ubuntu, and you can search in the shell, but not very good with the shell.

You use locate, find, which, whereis and so on, to search for files, and you can do it from the dash, but it would work the same way as in other shells, like bash or zsh.

I don't know how the 'recently used' search works on windows, but I guess the programs have to use a certain library, to work that way, and I see multiple problems.

If you start a program on linux, this file is read, some libraries are read, configurations in /etc/foo or ~/.foo are read, or maybe both. A single program can open hundrets of files, but most of them without the intent to modify them. But it can be filtered, such that only files, opened with the same file-open-dialog get protocolled.

But that would mean, that files, opened written with the gtk-toolkit would be protocolled, those written with Qt wouldn't.

But if they are moved with some tools, filemanager, command in the shell - the system will not update that change.

The same problem ocucurs, when you use removable storage like USB-Sticks, or modify files in the cloud from a different working place.