# Index Second Hard Drive to Search

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zeitgeist does not index folders in NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43831/zeitgeist-does-not-index-folders-in-ntfs-partition)

Well I just wanna find my files located on my second and third hard drive with ubuntu dash or synapse, because when I make a search with the both of it just show me results of the main hard drive and the most of my files are in the other drives.

Note: the others hard drives are ext4 too and mounted on /media/driveX

thank you