# forcing synapse to index a directory

Tags: synapse, updatedb

I have a NTFS drive binded into a directory inside my home (binding is specified in fstab), like this:

```
UUID=1A782A664EB8 /mnt/windows ntfs permissions,locale=en_US.utf8 0 2
/mnt/windows/Users/me/Documents /home/me/Documents none bind 0 0
```

The permissions are set 666 for files and 777 for directories.

This is my /etc/updatedb.conf:

```
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

NOTE: home directory is not encrypted.

It seems that synapse fails to index those files. Is there a way to force synapse to index that directory?

Comment: Maybe related: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2192348.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possibile, but disabled by default. I am not sure what will happen to the NTFS file system if you index it with `updatedb`.

The thing is, Synapse uses Zeitgeist, that uses `locate` to find things.

Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58234/29595) my `/etc/updatedb.conf` reads

```
cat /etc/updatedb.conf
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
# PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media /home/.ecryptfs /var/lib/schroot"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre tmpfs usbfs udf fuse.glusterfs fuse.sshfs curlftpfs ecryptfs fusesmb devtmpfs"
```

Where these variables are documented in

```
man updatedb.conf

[...]
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS
              One of the strings 0, no, 1 or yes.  If PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS  is  1
              or  yes,  bind  mounts are not scanned by updatedb(8).  All file
              systems mounted in the subtree of a bind mount  are  skipped  as
              well,  even  if they are not bind mounts.  As an exception, bind
              mounts of a directory on itself are not skipped.
```

So I would have to modify the first variale to `"no"` through

```
sudo nano /etc/updatedb.conf
```

Then modify it, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Then

```
sudo updatedb
```

and try to `locate` something on that mount point to see if it works.

I repeat it here at the very end of the post: I do not know what would happen to a NTFS file system when scanned by `updatedb` (will it take forever? will it crash? will it corrupt the FS? I really have no idea).

Comment: Thanks, I will try with setting: PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="no". But as far as I understand, that will scan everything, right?

Comment: All the binded mountpoints, yes. Then you can remove some of them by modifying the variable `PRUNEPATHS`, and writing there what you want to remove.

Comment: dadexix86: I updated the question while you were writing your answer.

Comment: @lepe ok, but I do not see how that update would modify my answer ;) Try with the "no" and let me know :)

Comment: ok I see. I think I misunderstood what "PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS" means. I think you are right. I will wait until "updatedb" finishes and let you know.

Comment: PRUNE_SOMETHING means "remove" that "something :) "to prune" is to cut some branches of trees, in order to making them growing better.

Comment: Great! that did the trick :) Thanks for your explanation... now its clear to me. (I had to logout so synapse also updated the search results)

Comment: Good to know! Till next time!