# How to search NTFS drives with Tracker? How to reduce the load of Tracker?

Tags: gnome, 19.04, tracker

Tracker is now the default in Ubuntu 19.04, and I can successfully search for files and file contents in /home on an ext4 formatted drive. But I would also like to be able to search my ntfs drives. So how can I enable Tracker to search ntfs drives in the gnome search?

[image: unable to find myfile.pdf located on NTFS drive]

So far I have added my NTFS drive in **Settings icon in the launcher -> Search -> Search Locations (gear icon)-> Other** and, like recommended in [Zeitgeist does not index folders in NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43831/zeitgeist-does-not-index-folders-in-ntfs-partition) I also removed /media from PRUNEPATHS, executed **sudo updatedb** and **rebooted** - all to no avail.

[image]

Also, I believe that Tracker is continuously running in the background and making my laptop slow. Can I mitigate the performance loss by deactivating indexing of file contents somehow?

[image]

Comment: Tracker is not installed on Ubuntu 17.10/18.04/18.10 by default. What version are you running? Perhaps a 16.04 Ubuntu Gnome version or an update thereof?

Comment: @vanadium i installed it manually. I want myfile.pdf to appear on gnome search.

Comment: Still don know what version of Linux you are on. File name search works without tracker from within Gnome Shell since 18.04 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer the "How to search NTFS drives with Tracker" part, but to answer the "**How to reduce the load of Tracker**" question:

Since tracker-preferences/tracker-gui are not available anymore in 19.04, you can use the **dconf-Editor** to edit Tracker's settings. If you are concerned about battery life or notebook performance while on battery, go to `/org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files/` and set **index-on-battery** to **False** .

To reduce CPU priority of Tracker, you can set **sched_idle** both in `/org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files/` and `/org/freedesktop/tracker/extract`
to **Always** (as in "always set Tracker to lowest CPU-priority") so Tracker only works when the CPU is not being used by another program.

See System Resource Management here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/Configuration